# Identify old gen in heap dump (or take heap dump of old gen only)

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I think I have a memory leak.
(they say the first step is admitting the problem, right?)

Anyway, I think I do - see attached image for heap by regions: [image: heap regions].
Green is Eden, blue/red is S0/S1, purple is old. I have unlimited tenuring (>15), lots of time passed between memory being allocated and it spilling to old gen. Hence - a memory leak. I think.

So - the question - how can I analyze what is leaking? As you can see, my Eden is very active. Lot's of objects being created and destroyed all the time.

Is there a way of taking a heap dump of the old gen only? Or somehow identify the old gen in a full heap dump (if so, with what tool)?

Edit 1:
Clarification: I'm not doing anything that *should* retain objects in memory. Everything I allocate after the initial startup should die young.

Edit2:
New findings: I took a heap dump, GCed like crazy and took another. The second one shows a significantly reduced level of old gen usage. The main difference between the two were objects held by finalizers.
Don't finalizers run in young GC cycles? Do they always wait for a full GC to be cleaned?

Comment: If you have a memory leak, I would expect that your overall heap usage would keep going up. Are you seeing that somewhere? Also, do you have verbosegc enabled on as an argument to the JVM?

Comment: @Disco 3: this is actually from jstat (gcutil). Overall heap is growing - as can be seen in the old gen - it grew from 18% to just under 20% and then to just over 21% - but it took hours, so I expect everything that should've died young would have done so already.

Comment: Ah yes - I couldn't see the purple line against the red background :-)

Comment: finalisation is described in http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/finalization/ it is basically a 2 pass collect (once to enqueue it with the finaliser thread and a 2nd time to finalise)

Answer (score 2):

seeing some things propagate to old gen isn't a huge concern. After your old gen reaches a certain threshold a full GC will kick off. If that isn't able to reclaim the memory then you have an issue. The fact that you are seeing some memory allocated during a young collection shouldn't be an alarming concern.

> lots of time passed between memory being allocated and it spilling to
>   old gen. Hence - a memory leak. I think

Not really.. just because memory is being added to old gen doesn't mean it is a memory leak. It is normal practice during a young collection that older objects get promoted to old gen. It is during those young collections when older objects get added to the old gen. This may just be your application still ramping up. In large scale applications there may be features not used every day, which may be getting into memory later then you expected.

That being said, if you really are concerned with any memory being added to the old gen and want to investigate further, I would recommend running this application on a demo environment. Attach a profiler (VisualVM will work) and load test (JMeter is good and free) your application. If you look at the objects you can get an idea of what generation an object is. You also want to see what happens when your old gen reaches a threshold where a full GC will kick off (normally in the 70%-90% range). If your old gen recovers back to the 20% threshold, then there is no leak. In some cases the old gen may never reach the point where a full GC gets kicked off, but instead level off as you expected. The load test will help identify that.

If it doesn't recover and you confirm you have a memory leak then you will want to capture a heap dump (hprof) and use a tool like MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool) to analyze the dump to find the culprit.

Comment: Yep. that's what we're doing (only replace JMeter with Load Runner and add Yourkit to VisualVM). The application is past its expected ramp-up though. It takes more than 75 minutes for the survivor space to get filled to the brim so it spills to old-gen (note that I'm using unlimited tenuring). My assumption is that if something is allocated during a single transaction (out of millions) and survives for 75 minutes, it's a leak.
Hence my original question - how do I identify what has leaked (or how do I filter Eden and S0/S1 out of the heap dump)?

Comment: my last paragraph should cover that. take the heap dump and look at it in MAT. there is a "leak suspect" tool you can use in MAT. I would recommend running your load test until your application is at its breaking point before taking this snapshot. This will make any problems stand out. Personally, I don't think this is a leak. Based on the graph you provided it looks like a full GC would kick off once every 4-5 days, which isn't terrible.

Comment: But I do understand your point of an object living for 75 minutes without being cleaned up looks like a memory leak.

Comment: I have never seen a way to determine what objects are in young/old gen. it is normally treated as one when doing heap dumps. Profiling is your best bet since it can track each individual object and know its generation

Comment: if it's a leak, tenured will gradually increase in size.. is that what is happening? If you can do a long running test then arguably reducing MTT to a minimum will reveal it sooner because you will force more tenured collections and hence it will be more obvious whether it is really leaking or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using JVisualVM (part of the JDK since Java 6 Build 10 or something like that), you can look at the TYPE of objects that are in memory. That will help you track down where the leak is. Of course, it takes a lot of digging into the code, but that's the best tool I've used that always available and reliable.

Watch out for objects being passed around, it could be that you have a handle that's being kept in a list or array that's not being cleared out. I find that if I watch the number of objects being created, and kept, in JVisualVM over a period of a few minutes, I usually get an idea of where in the code to go dig for the offending objects not being released.

Comment: nop. The type of the objects doesn't help me. Since this is a leak, some objects that I think die young, actually die old.

Comment: Would you be able to tell us what objects you create young? Perhaps there's a factory method or something else that keeps track of them, that might explain why they remain alive.

Comment: um - enterprise application, millions line of code, about 120 libraries - kinda hard :)

Comment: Great! So it's a 3rd party library and not your problem.  If they tell you something else, tell them to prove it...   Seriously though, unless you start running test scenarios with isolated sections, it might be a challenge to track down the actual culprits.